# Use RegexRouter to replace multiple dots in topics with underscores

Tags: apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

It seems like it's not possible to use the RegexRoute to replace all the dots in a topic name with underscores since RegexRouter calls `replaceFirst` not `replaceAll`. Is there a way around this? One thought I had was to take multiple passes with transform:

```
{
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkConnector",
    "tasks.max": "10",
    "topics": "foo.bar.baz,some.topic",
    "s3.region": "us-east-1",
    "s3.bucket.name": "bucket",
    "s3.part.size": "5242880",
    "s3.compression.type": "gzip",
    "timezone": "UTC",
    "rotate.schedule.interval.ms": "900000",
    "flush.size": "1000000",
    "storage.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.storage.S3Storage",
    "format.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.format.bytearray.ByteArrayFormat",
    "partitioner.class": "io.confluent.connect.storage.partitioner.TimeBasedPartitioner",
    "path.format": "'year'=YYYY/'month'=MM/'day'=dd/'hour'=HH",
    "timestamp.extractor": "RecordField",
    "timestamp.field": "time",
    "schema.compatibility": "NONE",
    "name": "s3-sink",
    "transforms":"replaceFirstDot,replaceSecondDot",
    "transforms.replaceFirstDot.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter",
    "transforms.replaceFirstDot.regex": "\\.",
    "transforms.replaceFirstDot.replacement": "_",
    "transforms.replaceSecondDot.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter",
    "transforms.replaceSecondDot.regex": "\\.",
    "transforms.replaceSecondDot.replacement": "_"
}
```

Is there an easy way to include a custom partitioner or transformation/router?

Comment: Is the idea here that in S3 you write under foo_bar_baz_some_topic instead of foo.bar.baz,some.topic ?